# What's reason for Django contrib.auth duplicated URL routes?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Django newbie here - Futzing around the contrib.auth module, noticed a couple places where there were additional routes defined:

From `/django/contrib/auth/urls.py`

```
# The views used below are normally mapped in django.contrib.admin.urls.py
# This URLs file is used to provide a reliable view deployment for test purposes.
# It is also provided as a convenience to those who want to deploy these URLs
# elsewhere.
```

What does "reliable view deployment for test purposes" mean, and what does "deploy these URLs elsewhere" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The url patterns are used in Django's tests, e.g. [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cf6ce279c7671a4c83c960c5c526f92679a4fac8/tests/auth_tests/test_views.py#L130) and [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cf6ce279c7671a4c83c960c5c526f92679a4fac8/tests/flatpages_tests/urls.py#L12). It's reliable because it's including the same set of views mapped to the same urls everywhere.

You can also use these urls in your own project (i.e. deploy these urls elsewhere):

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) for more information. However, if you want more customization (e.g. use the url `/signin/` instead of `/login/`), then you need to add individual url patterns to your urls.py, instead of including the entire `django.contrib.auth.urls`.